# Array merge or combine in php

Tags: php, arrays

$arr1 is for all values. Here `checked=false`.

```
$arr1 = [{"event_id":"2","name":"I have a new message","checked":"false"},{"event_id":"3","name":"A meeting awaits
     me","checked":"false"},{"event_id":"4","name":"Someone visited my profil","checked":"false"},{"event_id"
    :"5","name":"Someone like my profile","checked":"false"},{"event_id":"6","name":"My picture was approved"
    ,"checked":"false"},{"event_id":"7","name":"My picture was rejected","checked":"false"},{"event_id":"8"
    ,"name":"VIP purchase confirmation","checked":"false"}];
```

$arr2 is for only checked values. Here `checked=true`.

```
$arr2 = [{"event_id":"2","name":"I have a new message","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"3","name":"A meeting awaits
     me","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"4","name":"Someone visited my profil","checked":"true"},{"event_id"
    :"5","name":"Someone like my profile","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"7","name":"My picture was rejected"
    ,"checked":"true"},{"event_id":"8","name":"VIP purchase confirmation","checked":"true"}]
```

Now I want an array like below, where "checked":"false" and "checked":"true" both will be there. How is that possible?

```
$arr3 = [{"event_id":"2","name":"I have a new message","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"3","name":"A meeting awaits
     me","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"4","name":"Someone visited my profil","checked":"true"},{"event_id"
    :"5","name":"Someone like my profile","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"6","name":"My picture was approved"
    ,"checked":"false"},{"event_id":"7","name":"My picture was rejected","checked":"true"},{"event_id":"8"
    ,"name":"VIP purchase confirmation","checked":"true"}];
```

Comment: Php array hasn't object in it.

Comment: Make them PHP arrays first?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This are obvioulsy json-strings.

Comment: @SubhankarBhattacharjee. I have provided with a Example method of how to solve your issue. Share thoughts about it. let me know if you face any hindrance in development.

Comment: @SubhankarBhattacharjee. Check my updated answer now. The last part is used for removing of the duplicates from the merged array. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> You Question need to be like this: **MERGE JSON OBJECTS**

It is pretty much easier to join `json_objects` into a `single array` by following the below steps.

1. You need to perform the `json_decode()` for the `$arr1` and `$arr2`
2. Then after performing the `json_decode()` you need to use the `array_merge()` since after `json_decode()` your data will be as `array()` and hence you are comfortable to merge two arrays.
3. Last step if you need the output as the `json_object()` again you need to perform the `json_encode()` for the resultant array that you get after the `array_merge()`

### Example for your Scenario

```
<?php
$json_first = '{
    "id": "#001",
    "username": "Name One",
    "type": "ADMIN",
    "status": "ACTIVE"   
}';

$json_second =  '{
    "id": "#002",
    "username": "Name Two",
    "type": "USER",
    "status": "INACTIVE"
}';
$user_info[] = json_decode($json_first,TRUE);
$user_info[] = json_decode($json_second,TRUE);
$json_merge = json_encode($user_info);
?>

<h4>Given JSON String:</h4> 
<p>
<div>$json1 = <?php echo $json1; ?></div>
<div>$json2 = <?php echo $json2; ?></div>
</p>
<h4>Output:</h4> 
<div><?php echo $json_merge; ?></div>
```

**Output:**

**Given JSON Strings**

```
{"id": "#001", "username": "Name One", "type": "ADMIN", "status": "ACTIVE" }
{"id": "#002", "username": "Name Two", "type": "USER","status": "INACTIVE" }
```

**JSON After Merge:**

```
[{"id": "#001", "username": "Name One", "type": "ADMIN", "status": "ACTIVE" },{"id": "#002", "username": "Name Two", "type": "USER","status": "INACTIVE" }]
```

> Getting **ARRAY MERGE** by **removing Duplicates**.

If you need to merge the array and remove the duplicate values you can prefer the `array_unique()` function.

This will remove up all the duplicate's and then you can perform the operations that is needed by you.

```
<?php
$array_unique_result = array_unique($array_merge_result,SORT_REGULAR); // This will provide the unique values alone after the array is merged.
$json = json_encode($array_unique_result);
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Here duplicate values will come. I need array_merge if not exists.

Comment: Array merge should not come duplicate values as per the requirement right :)

Comment: I have updated my answer for removing the Duplicates after the array merge and then get the output. Thanks :)